# This is the register form for my application .What went wrong in this.Database is not getting created

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlite

```
package prad.com.cat;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="USERDATABASE.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
 private static final String Table_UserDetails="UserInformation";
 public static  final String Column_UserName="Name";
 public static final String Column_UserEmail="E-mail";
 public static final String Column_UserPhoneNo="Phonen NO";
 public static final String Column_UserPassword="Password";
 public static final String Column_UserConfirmPassword="Confirm Password";
 public static final String Column_UserSecurityPassword="Security Password";
public DatabaseHelper(Context context,String name,CursorFactory factory,int version) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME ,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
Details d=new Details();
DatabaseHelper dbh;
SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String DATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE" +Table_UserDetails + "("+Column_UserName+"TEXT,"+Column_UserEmail+"TEXT," +Column_UserPhoneNo+"TEXT,"+Column_UserPassword+"TEXT,"+Column_UserConfirmPassword+"TEXT,"+Column_UserSecurityPassword+"TEXT"+");";
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" +Table_UserDetails);
onCreate(db);// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
/*public void insertDetails(String username,String useremail,String userphoneno,String userpassword,String userconfirmpassword,String usersecuritypassword ){
    ContentValues v=new ContentValues();
    v.put(Column_UserName, d.getName());
    v.put(Column_UserEmail, d.getEmail());
    v.put(Column_UserPhoneNo,d.getPhoneno());
    v.put(Column_UserPassword, d.getPassword());
    v.put(Column_UserConfirmPassword, d.getConfirmpassword());
    v.put(Column_UserSecurityPassword, d.getSecuritypassword());
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(Table_UserDetails, null, v);
    db.close();
}*/
public String findpassword(String spassword){
    String query="SELECT * FROM" +Table_UserDetails +"WHERE"+Column_UserPassword + " =  \"" +spassword+"\"" ;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String s;
    if(c.getCount()>0){
        c.moveToFirst();
        //d.setpassword(c.getString(3));
    s=  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Column_UserPassword));
        //return s;
    }
    else{
        s=null;
    }
    //return s;\
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return s;



}
  public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance(){
    return db;
}
 public void insertDetails(String username, String useremail,
        String userphone, String userpassword, String userconfirmpassword,
        String usersecuritypassword) {
//  Details d=new Details();

    ContentValues v=new ContentValues();
    v.put(Column_UserName, username);
    v.put(Column_UserEmail, useremail);
    v.put(Column_UserPhoneNo,userphone);
    v.put(Column_UserPassword, userpassword);
    v.put(Column_UserConfirmPassword, userconfirmpassword);
    v.put(Column_UserSecurityPassword, usersecuritypassword);
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(Table_UserDetails, null, v);
    db.close();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

This is the register form for my application. But I don't understand what went wrong as the database is not created. The CREATE_TABLE part I'm not sure about the syntax I guess it might be the problem. Or any other problem I'm not sure , so please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing spaces in your queries. i.e.

```
String DATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE" +Table_UserDetails + "("+Column_UserName+"TEXT,"....
```

When you debug and look at the string your code will look something like:

CREATE TABLEmyAppTable(columnName)TEXT,

Should be:

```
String DATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE " +Table_UserDetails + " ("+Column_UserName+" TEXT,"....
```

Put the spaces in and it should work. :)

Comment: how to check if the database is been created in DDMS.

Comment: I tried in FILE EXPLORER but don't find anything related to that database folder

Comment: By default Android will put your database file in /data/data/your.app.name/databases/. You can use adb to direct commands to the database as well by using
 "adb shell" then entering "sqlite3 <path to your db file>"
Then send sqlite commands directly on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
String DATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE" +Table_UserDetails + "
  ("+Column_UserName+"TEXT,"+Column_UserEmail+"TEXT,"  +
  Column_UserPhoneNo+"TEXT,"+Column_UserPassword+"TEXT,"+
  Column_UserConfirmPassword+"TEXT,"+
  Column_UserSecurityPassword+"TEXT"+");";
```

you are going to need some spaces between keyword and the text

e.g.

```
String DATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE " +Table_UserDetails + "
```

You have the same issues for column names as well.

Examine your `DATABASE_CREATE` string before execution.

Comment: I tried it. But it doesn't work. Can you please elaborate about it. How to check in DDMS whether the database is been created or not.

Comment: surround your execSQL with a `try / catch block` and report any error